# Other than burn-in increase and priors, how can I help my multiple change point (mcp package in R) models converge?

Tags: r, linear-regression, piecewise

I would like to identify changepoints in my data and an associated error term for their estimate. The mcp package seems to do a good job (visually) of identifying changepoints in my data, but the model parameters generally have rhat values >1.1. From my understanding, I cannot trust any Bayesian parameter estimates unless *all* rhat values in the model are =< 1.1. Aside from increasing my burn-in period with the adapt argument or using priors (see note below), how else can I improve these models?

Alternatively, can I force mcp to fit a 'best' two and three segment model and return those parameter estimates with error? Ideally I would be able to provide changepoint estimates with an error term associated with each estimate, but packages like segmented and struccchange generally fail to identify changepoints in my data.

The code looks like this:

```
set.seed(42)

x <- c(227,227,228,228,228,228,228,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,232,233,233,233,233,233,233,233,233,236,236,236,236,237,237,237,238,238,238,238,238,238,238,238,239,239,239,239,239,239,243,244,244,244,244,244,244,244,244,244,245,245,245,246,246,246,246,247,250,250,250,250,251,251,251,251,251,251,251,251,253,253,253,257,257,260,260,260,260,260,260,260,264,264,264,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,265,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,271,271,271,271,271,271,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,273,274,274,274,274,274,274,274)

y <- c(8.43,6.9,8.93,7.33,7.28,7.24,6.62,8.36,8.17,8.07,8.07,7.63,7.6,7.54,7.37,7.31,7.21,7.03,6.93,6.88,6.82,6.78,6.7,6.5,8.35,10.97,7.48,7.46,7.28,7.17,6.72,6.68,6.08,7.42,7.14,6.92,6.68,7.49,7.28,6.67,9.4,7.54,7.04,6.89,6.88,6.52,6.45,6.39,8.48,8.04,7.52,7.35,6.9,6.57,6.86,7.46,7.39,7.16,7.08,6.83,6.83,6.7,6.54,6.47,9.75,7.38,5.96,10.49,8.32,7.22,7.05,8.55,10.34,8.23,7.9,7.31,8.18,7.8,7.31,7.18,7.17,7.13,7.02,6.84,10.62,10.09,9.26,10.8,10.37,10.9,10.52,10.23,9.28,9.18,8.85,8.81,11.03,8.84,6.29,11.36,10.91,10.87,10.4,10.17,9.61,9.5,9.36,9.17,9.13,8.88,8.73,8.55,8.37,8.33,8.25,7.82,6.9,9.77,9.53,9.39,9.1,8.93,8.68,8.64,8.47,8.41,8.38,8.28,8.18,7.74,10.67,10.64,10.54,10.36,10.35,7.03,9.51,9.37,9.24,9.22,9.18,8.96,8.95,8.94,8.89,8.82,8.79,8.72,8.35,8.22,8.13,8.07,7.91,7.85,7.79,8.82,8.59,8.44,8.42,8.37,8.06,7.34)

df <- data.frame(x, y)

#Writing the formula for a three-segment line
three_segment_model = list(
  y ~ x,          # intercept + slope
  y ~ 1 ~ 0 + x, #segment 2, specifying a changepoint and joined slope
  y ~ 1 ~ 0 + x #segment 3, specifying a changepoint and joined slope
)

#Writing the formula for a two-segment line
two_segment_model = list(
  y ~ x,          # intercept + slope
  y ~ 1 ~ 0 + x #segment 2, specifying a changepoint and joined slope
)

#Disjointing the slopes of two segments
test_segment_model = list(
  y ~ x,          # intercept + slope
  y ~ 1 ~ 1 + x #segment 2, specifying a changepoint and disjoined slope
)

#Disjointing the slopes of the three expected segments
test_three_segment_model = list(
  y ~ x,          # intercept + slope
  y ~ 1 ~ 1 + x, #segment 2, specifying a changepoint and disjoined slope
  y ~ 1 ~ 1 + x #segment 3, specifying a changepoint and disjoined slope
)
```

These are the models I've tried, but none achieve consistently tolerable rhat values. The code I use to test them is as follows:

```
#An example run, although each of these models fails to provide suitable rhat values
fit1 <- mcp(three_segment_model, df, chains = 4, iter = 10000, cores = 3)
plot(fit1)
fit1_summary <- data.frame(summary(fit1))
```

Given the literature, I have also tried priors (though admittedly I cannot make heads or tails of the truncate and distribution code with mcp), which do not seem to reflect the patterns poorly identified with this modelling approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is primarily a practical one, upping the number of iterations and chains reveals that the posterior is quite reproducible across chains for the "problematic" parameters:

```r
fit1 <- mcp(three_segment_model, df, chains = 6, iter = 50000, cores = 6)
plot_pars(fit1, c("cp_1", "cp_2", "x_1"))
```

[image]

And you have good `rhat` values for the non-three-segment models; all pointing to the three-segment model being unidentifiable with this data. Without knowing the process, I did try some fairly informative priors:

```r
prior = list(
  x_1 = 0,  # fixed horizontal!
  x_2 = "dnorm(0, 1) T(0, )"  # Positive slope
)
```

but it did not improve rhat values for the change point parameters.